# How to display time without colon in sas

Tags: sas

how can I display range of time with no colon?

```
data alltime;
do hr = '00:00:00't to '23:59:59't;
output; end; format hr time8.; run;
```

02:23:30 => 022330

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about `B8601TM6.` format?

```
data _null_;
  do hr = '00:00:00't to '23:59:59't by 65*60+23 ;
    put  hr time8. '->' hr b8601tm6. ;
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
 0:00:00->000000
 1:05:23->010523
 2:10:46->021046
 3:16:09->031609
 4:21:32->042132
 5:26:55->052655
 6:32:18->063218
 7:37:41->073741
 8:43:04->084304
 9:48:27->094827
10:53:50->105350
11:59:13->115913
13:04:36->130436
14:09:59->140959
15:15:22->151522
16:20:45->162045
17:26:08->172608
18:31:31->183131
19:36:54->193654
20:42:17->204217
21:47:40->214740
22:53:03->225303
23:58:26->235826
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked out like that:

```
data alltime;
do hr = '00:00:00't to '23:59:59't;
output; end; format hr b8601tm8.; run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Toe remove colon
%let systm=%sysfunc(compress(%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(datetime(),datetime26.),:,))));
%put =&systm;

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYSTM resolves to 23JUN2023101122
=23JUN2023101122

Comment: Please format your answer. Use a code fence.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the CAT function in SAS to concatenate the hours, minutes, and seconds components of the time value.

```
data alltime;
  format hr time8.;
  do hr = '00:00:00't to '23:59:59't;
    time_str = cat(of hour(hr) minute(hr) second(hr), ' ');
    output;
  end;
  drop hr;
run;
```

Comment: That cannot work for 2 reasons.  First is the OF keyword is for variable lists, not general expressions like function calls.  Second is that if that is fixed then the strings generated will be confusing when any of hour, minute or second is less than 10.